# I need help with this error please: Could not write to output file...file is being used by another process.

Tags: c#, winforms

Could not write to output file 'C:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Application 2\Application 2\obj\x86\Debug\Application 2.exe' -- 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'

I have been getting this error since last weekend. I have searched it on the web and found a few solutions which I have tried to no avail.

- I have closed all my design views and then tried running.
- I have closed ALL windows and then tried running.
- I have unloaded the project and reloaded it.
- I have deleted the 'obj'-folder in my 'application 2'-folder.
- I have closed Visual Studio and reopened my project via the start page as well as via the solution exe.
- I have edited the pre-build event command line with something that supposedly unlocks the file and then tries building it.
- I have downloaded 'ProcessExplorer' to try and identify a process that might be locking this file and ending it.
  -I have even done a total system restore to 3 weeks ago in-case there was an issue.

Some of these solutions worked the first time I did it, but thereafter it doesn't.

The only thing that seems to be working consistently is if I restart my computer. It then builds one to four times successfully, but then starts giving me this error.

I haven't done anything drastically different in my code that might affect my project in such a way to suddenly give me this error. I am using C# and doing a winforms application connecting to a postgresql database.

Just a note: It did this before, but then I just click NO to run previous build and rerun it, then it works. It now is a permanent problem.

I hope someone would be able to help me with a fix for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems your App has a problem stopping (in/by the debugger). Do you use any foreground threads, ActiveX etc?  Any problems with other projects?

Comment: It seems to have been my antivirus. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your virus scanner is getting in the way. Try to disable real time scanning and if that helps.

Comment: I am using Panda Cloud and ImmuneNet. Panda did some update last weekend. But my system restore was done to before that update and still got the same issue. How to I deal with it if this is the problem? Anti-virus should stay on shouldn't it?

Comment: switch it off to see if this is your problem. If it is the problem then you can make an exception for the files or folders that need it.

Comment: I've added my project-folder to the excluded from scans. So will keep eye on it to see if it gives more issues.

Comment: IT looks like this has worked. I had to add it to both my anti virus exceptions. But it seems that it was Immunenet giving the problem. I've now added and removed it 3 times and when it is removed it runs once, when I change code it gives error. When it is included no problems running. Hope it stays that way. Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problems when using third-party addons that are supposed to analyze code and things like that.

There must be something attaching to your program that does not get properly closed/disposed/etc. when the program ends.

I would look around and see if you can find anything that may be using your executable.  Then you can try to turn this off, or use the task manager to kill the process.

Comment: The strange thing is, I have 3 extensions which I have been using for the past year without major issues: brace completer, italic comments, and theme colour changer. Other than that no add-ons or extensions.

Answer (score 0):

In the "xxxx.csproj" file,search the file name 'Application 2.exe'

If you see the following XML

```
<Reference Include="Application 2">
  <HintPath>obj\Debug\Application 2.exe</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**remove！！~~~**